# Invalid Parameters on playing youtube embedded on a website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, youtube, youtube-api

At first I'm getting this error ***"This video contains content from sme. It is restricted from playback on certain sites"*** Then after reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543238/has-youtube-iframe-embed-has-stopped-working-for-certain-videos?rq=1) I added few lines to my youtube emded url I'm now receiving a new error which says ***"Invalid Paramaters"***. By the way what I'm trying to do here is embed a youtube video on my site.

This is the original embed url of the youtube I'm trying to embed on my website. Where I'm receiving the error message *"This video contains content from SME. It is restricted from playback on certain sites. Watch on Youtube"*.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CFqbhsvXE7M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is the editted one after reading the post. And getting this error *"Invalid Paramaters"*.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CFqbhsvXE7M?playlist=." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I've done some research and it says **YouTube indeed has changed their API over the last couple of days and flash fallback from their HTML5 Video Player fails**. and I didn't find a clear explanation how to fix it. Using the original embed url the youtube plays well in my localhost. After I deployed it in a server I'm now receiving those errors. Is this something to do with the domain of the server I'm using? 
 **Question:**
How could I possibly fix this? T_T
**Other Information:** I'm using asp.net MVC3

Comment: **[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15337890/2007801)**

Comment: sorry no luck still receiving the error message

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `embed` use `watch` and add in a few attributes, works all the time:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" 
   src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFqbhsvXE7M" 
   frameborder="0" 
   webkitAllowFullScreen 
   mozallowfullscreen 
   allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Comment: my youtube video now cannot be view..T_T

Comment: You can **NOT** view it anymore? I just [viewed it here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFqbhsvXE7M).

Comment: I can view it directly on youtube. I can also view it using my localhost. But I'm receiving the error above when I deployed it on the server. btw the link that you provided points directly on the youtube page of the video which will not work on a website. I'm using the Embed Url below it instead.

Comment: The code I gave you is what I'm using. It works both on the public and secured side of things (logged-in and anonymous users). If you do that, YouTube converts the url to something it can work with. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: yeah.. but the youtube could not be found this time on my site like my above comment T_T. I think there is some other reason that restrict it from playing.